# What is a dhampir's max lifespan?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, races, aging

What is the maximum lifespan of dhampirs? Are they semi-immortal like undead creatures, do they have lifespans similar to those of humans, or are their lifespans in between these extremes?

Comment: what source are you using for dhampirs?  UA?  VR's Guide to Ravenloft?  They aren't core, so it might be helpful to readers to point out where you got the PC race from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### This is probably up to you to decide as your write your back story.

The first thing that is immediately evident as I reread the Dhampir lineage rules is that *lifespan is never explicitly stated*.

Delving further, a review of the Dhampir origins table seems to support the idea that is up to you. Some of the origins seem consistent with you being immortal, others seem consistent with you being mortal.

For example, option 2 on the table is:

> Your pact with a predatory deity, fiend, fey, or spirit causes you to share their hunger.

It seems entirely reasonable for such a pact to include an immortality clause. On the other hand, option 4 is:

> A parasite lives inside you. You indulge its hunger.

Here, it is entirely reasonable that you are entirely mortal, and a parasitic organism drives you to consume raw flesh.

Thus, the idea seems to be that it is up to you to decide this as you work with the DM to craft your backstory.

Comment: Wouldn't option 2 mean that all warlocks can logically be immortal if 'it is entirely reasonable'?

Comment: @SeriousBri Sure, why not?

Comment: @SeriousBri age almost never has an impact on mechanics (with very rare exceptions), only on roleplay. You should probably consult your DM first, but in general, saying that your warlock pact includes immortality (only including aging, of course) shouldn't be too big of a problem.

Comment: @PixelMaster There are a few aging effects out there, but "immunity to this one niche effect" shouldn't be too concerning.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Age trait was left out for all the VRGtR Lineages. I think that Jeremy Crawford may have addressed this/discussed the reasoning in a Sage Advice video segment, which may be useful to include in an answer if someone is able to find it. (I know you're not a fan of the unofficial rulings on Twitter, but this would be more of a designer acknowledgment/commentary about the lack of an Age trait here and why it is that way.)

Comment: Age hasn't been a major factor in D&D since 2nd edition anyway from what I can recall.

Comment: @AllanMills Most races in 5e are given natural lifespans and there are some effects that can rapidly age a creature, such that a creature near the end of their natural lifespan risks dying if subjected to such an effect.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Are there actual rules to that effect in 5E? I don't recall seeing any.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131473/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-allan-mills).